# Convert MBR to GPT on already dual-booted system without data loss

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have dual booted system `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Windows 8` with `Grub2`. I plan to convert MBR to GPT. I was looking at [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/)
and just need to know whether it will preserve my dual boot. Also if I have any other better alternatives?

Here's how my partitions look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The bulk of your OS installations should be fine after the conversion, providing the software does what it should; ***HOWEVER,*** boot loaders are different for MBR and GPT disks. I'm not familiar with AOMEI's partition table conversion tools, but assuming it converts *only* the partition table, the boot loader differences mean that your disk will be rendered unbootable after the conversion. If AOMEI does something to boot loaders, the disk might end up booting in one or both OSes, but this is really the tricky part of the conversion, so even if the tool claims to handle it, I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work.

It *is* possible to do an MBR-to-GPT conversion and keep your OS(es) bootable, but extra steps are likely to be required. For Windows, see [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403232647/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) for details. For Ubuntu, the easiest approach may be to use [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) Note, however, that Windows will boot from a GPT disk only if your computer has an [Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) firmware (or Unified EFI, which is EFI 2.x). Most computers introduced since mid-2011 have EFIs, so if your computer is less than about five years old, you should be OK on that score. If your computer is older than that, though, chances are you won't get Windows booting after such a conversion -- at least, not easily. If your computer is in the transition period, research its capabilities carefully.

Even if your computer has an EFI, you should heed the wisdom of the old saying, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." Converting from MBR to GPT (and therefore from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting) is risky; about a million different things can go wrong in such a conversion, resulting in anything from a few minutes' extra effort to the total and catastrophic loss of all data on your computer. The worst of these consequences are unlikely, but if you don't *need* to make this conversion, why risk it? Your question provides no motivation for making the change, so that question isn't really rhetorical -- you may have a valid motivation that you haven't described. If you're doing this on a whim or because you've heard GPT is "better" than MBR, though, I strongly advise against such a conversion. (GPT does have advantages over MBR, but those advantages are not worth risking the hassle of such a conversion in most cases.)

Comment: Enjoying again reading something worded by @Rod Smith. You bring it to the point in such a nice way...

Answer (score 0):

On MBR-partitioned drives the first stage of Grub is installed in the MBR (sector 0) and stage 1.5 resides in the sectors 1-62.

The GPT header resides in sector 1 and the partition-table-entries will occupy the sectors 2-33.

Converting from MBR to GPT will destroy Grubs stage 1.5 which resides in this sectors and the system will not be bootable unless you reinstall Grub.

You also would need a /boot-partition for Ubuntu.

The existing partitions itself should be preserved, but you have to pay attention to the first and the last partition on the drive. If the first partition starts in a sector lower then 34 you will loose data on the partition (That will mostly not be the case but you have to check it before converting).

You need at least 34 sectors free space at the very end of the disk for the backup of the GPT-partition-table. If the last partition on the drive ends in that area you have to resize the partition first, otherwise the end of this partition will be overwritten by the GPT-partition-table-backup.

So converting from MBR to GPT will require a quiet difficult workaround.
If your system runs fine with MBR then it might be better to leave it as it is. Never change a running system.

See the difference of Grubs location regarding MBR and GPT on this [Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB)

Comment: There's a 2 MiB gap at the end of the disk, and most modern tools leave sufficient space at the start of the disk for the GPT data structures, so chances are the MBR-to-GPT conversion itself would work smoothly. I agree with you about GRUB, though, and it gets worse for Windows (as noted in my answer), so I agree with your advice to not attempt this conversion -- at least, not without a compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some free alternatives:

1. mbr2gpt: https://chrunos.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-windows
2. GPTGen: https://github.com/xorangekiller/gptgen
3. DiskGenius: https://www.diskgenius.com/manual/convert-partition-table-style.php

Note that some of the above (eg. GPTGen), appear to have some caveats to usage which you should make sure are met before starting, since otherwise it may cause your device to fail to boot: "Some implementations of GPT (e.g. Windows) require certain partitions to be present on the disk (e.g. an EFI boot partition). Gptgen doesn't create these partitions, it can only convert the existing partition table's contents. To create such partitions, use a GPT-ready partition manager such as parted."

I haven't tried any of the tools above myself, so if someone finds that one of them is indeed capable of converting MBR to GPT -- and especially if it can do so with minimal usage of other tools and commands -- please let us know in the comments.

---

Regarding AOMEI, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1132654/convert-mbr-to-gpt-on-already-dual-booted-system-without-data-loss#comment2222637_1132660) for my comment on it. It worked fine for cloning from an MBR ssd to a GPT ssd, but it doesn't have a "convert same drive" function, so I couldn't use it for my second computer.

P.S. There is also [Niubi Partition Editor](https://www.hdd-tool.com/disk-converter/convert-mbr-disk-to-gpt.html), however it looks very similar to [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), so I suspect it might be a clone of it. (even if not, it is likely to have the same restriction where you have to pay to unlock its MBR->GPT disk-conversion)

Answer (score -1):

AOMEI should convert MBR to GPT with just a few clicks, without data loss. Other methods such as DISKPART would erase data. Either way, I'd recommend backing up important data before making such a change.

Comment: But my question is will it/does it claim to preserve OS installations after the conversion?

Comment: For reference: I just used AOMEI to clone my MBR ssd to a GPT ssd, and it worked fine (and this was my primary drive with my OS on it). That said, I tried to convert my other pc's MBR ssd to GPT "in place", but it doesn't support that. (it only has a "clone drive" button, no "convert same drive")

MiniTool Partition Wizard claims to support in-place conversion: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/will-converting-mbr-to-gpt-erase-all-the-disk-partitions.html

But note that the free version doesn't let you convert your system/OS drive. (so I couldn't test it)

Answer (score -2):

Also, your dualboot should be fine. If anything, burn PLOP onto a disk, use it to boot Linux, and repair GRUB. Should be good from there.

Comment: No, the boot will most likely not survive such a conversion; see my answer.